# How to group text with words in common?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a list of unique values.
The list reports some different cases of the same products, like CO2 Detector 077, CO2 Detector 078, ...
How can I group them in one cell, counting all of the Detectors in the first cell that appears in the list? Probably using a counter of number of characters.

List of products:

```
Sonda Produto
Sonda Aspiração NTC060WF
Display CX660
XM679K Sonda 5/6
XM679K Sonda 3
Paragem Moveis Negativos
Detector CO2 Posto 077
Detector CO2 Posto 078
Detector CO2 Posto 080
Detector CO2 Posto 081
Interruptor Local
Resistência Desemb.
Cortina Automatica
Detector CO2 Posto 320
Detector CO2 Posto 321
Resistência Bateria
Sonda Humidade XH20P
Segurança KP69
Detector CO2 Posto 322
Detector CO2 Posto 323
Detector CO2 Posto 324
Detector CO2 Posto 326
```

Comment: can you post some sample of desired output?

Comment: is [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NmGbH.png) what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: I want to group all the Detector and count them all in a single cell. Making a list of general products and counting all but CO2 detector are the same only changing the place they are. Soo I will count all using a char counter in VBA Excel

**Detector CO2 - (X numbers)**

Comment: @Jeeped from the column A i want to count the total CO2 Detectors in another Column but in a single cell using a char function. Like: if it is a CO2 Detector doesn't mather if it is Posto 077, Posto 078, Posto 080, etc..

Comment: Reaarange your data so that the `Product Name` and `Identifier` are in separate columns; then use a Pivot Table.

Answer (score 1):

You say you want to count CO2 Detectors but all of your CO2 Detectors are listed as Detector CO2s. Try,

```
=countifs(a:a, "*detector*", a:a, "*co2*")
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't provide a lot of information.  My approach would be to split off the "identifier" for the product type, and then construct a pivot table.

But you'll have to figure out how to do the splitting.

As a quick and easy example, I used `Power Query` (aka `Get&Transform` in Excel 2016), to split by space but only the rightmost space. Then I closed and loaded it to a Pivot Table Report.

I then dragged the first column to the Rows area, and the Second column to the Values area.

A little formatting and:

[image]

Of course, you may need a more appropriate method of splitting your data, but this approach should get you started.

Also, if you also drag the 2nd column to the rows area, you can develop a pivot table in which you can drill down to the individual items, should you want.